# Calling sequential functions within a function in R

Tags: r, function, sequence

Given a series of functions ***B1, B2, .., B20***

How can you create a function that calls all or some of these predefined functions simultaneously?

What I want for example is a `function(start=B1,end=B12)` that will call `B1 TO B12` functions at the same time.

Comment: By simultaneously, do you mean in parallel or just so that you don't have to run them manually?

Comment: So that i don't have to run them manually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting all your functions in a list:

```
B <- list(B1, B2, ..., B20)
```

That way you can call them with another function:

```
callB <- function(callnum, ...){
  for(i in callnum){
    B[[i]](...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can it be a function with two arguments setting the interval of the functions to be called? Like if I want to call functions B8-B15 instead of always starting at B1

Comment: You can specify any that you want. For 8-15 you could use `callB(8:15)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct any R object name as a string and then `get` it.

```
> B1 = function(x){x^1}
> B2 = function(x){x^2}
> B3 = function(x){x^3}
> B4 = function(x){x^4}
> getBN = function(N){get(paste0("B",N))}
> getBN(1)
function(x){x^1}
> getBN(2)(2)
[1] 4
```

If you really want to do this I'd define your function like this:

```
doBs = function(start=1, end=12, prefix="B"){..stuff happens..}
```

and that function would be a loop over `start:end`, construct the function name, evaluate it.

If you really want to call it like `doBs(start=B1, end=B2)` then you need to get the names of the things passed which you can do with `deparse` and `substitute`:

```
doBs = function(start=B1){first = deparse(substitute(start));first}

> doBs()
[1] "B1"
> doBs(B2)
[1] "B2"
>
```

and then splitting the string and working out the start/end values to construct all the function names as string from B{start} to B{end} and then `get`ting them and calling them.

**Or do the right thing and stick the functions in a list.**

Comment: This is definitely the evil option, but it does more faithfully answer the question as it stands.